# How do I get the formula as text in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Essentially I’m looking for an equivalent/alternative to the MS Excel Function `FORMULATEXT(...)` in LO Calc…

In MS Excel, I can do the following:

`=FORMULATEXT(B3)`

... which will return the function contained in cell B3 as text (*great for teaching, notes, etc*.)

Microsoft FORMULATEXT Documentation:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8

Comment: [**=FORMULA(B3)**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060104.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3150688)

Comment: Thanks @JohnSUN, make it an answer, & I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Calc it is written as
[**=FORMULA(B3)**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060104.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3150688)